# how to fix the kubernetes CIDRNotAvailable issue

Tags: kubernetes

After I join the kuberentes(`v1.28.3`) node like this:

```
kubeadm join 172.29.217.209:6443 --token jew814.e5iof6qwvzg46d9q --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:21919c93d652
```

the node still remain notready state:

```
│ Allocated resources:                                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│   (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│   Resource           Requests  Limits                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│   --------           --------  ------                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│   cpu                0 (0%)    0 (0%)                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│   memory             0 (0%)    0 (0%)                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│   ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)    0 (0%)                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│   hugepages-1Gi      0 (0%)    0 (0%)                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│   hugepages-2Mi      0 (0%)    0 (0%)                                                                                                                                                                                                           │
│ Events:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         │
│   Type    Reason                   Age                  From             Message                                                                                                                                                                │
│   ----    ------                   ----                 ----             -------                                                                                                                                                                │
│   Normal  NodeHasSufficientMemory  27m (x5 over 27m)    kubelet          Node k8sslave01 status is now: NodeHasSufficientMemory                                                                                                                 │
│   Normal  NodeHasNoDiskPressure    27m (x5 over 27m)    kubelet          Node k8sslave01 status is now: NodeHasNoDiskPressure                                                                                                                   │
│   Normal  NodeHasSufficientPID     27m (x5 over 27m)    kubelet          Node k8sslave01 status is now: NodeHasSufficientPID                                                                                                                    │
│   Normal  RegisteredNode           27m                  node-controller  Node k8sslave01 event: Registered Node k8sslave01 in Controller                                                                                                        │
│   Normal  CIDRNotAvailable         103s (x10 over 27m)  cidrAllocator    Node k8sslave01 status is now: CIDRNotAvailable
```

I am using calico as the network component. what should I do to fixed this issue?